# Are non-disposed resources freed when an object is garbage collected?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I was posed this question, and while I believe I know the answer, I believe I should be 100% certain else I start spreading misinformation!

I have this object:

```
public class MyObj(){
    private SqlConnection conn;

    public MyObj(string connString){
        var stream = File.Open(@"c:\\file.txt");
        conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    }
}
```

When this object is created, a file handle is associated with the file, and a connection to a database is created. Neither has `Dispose` called on it as they should.

When this object goes out of scope and is eventually garbage collected, are these two resources then released, or do they remain in memory?

Comment: Note that `private File file;` is made up code, System.IO.File is static.

Comment: Yikes, still early here! Code sample has been edited.

Comment: The new code has new issues, but never mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When this object goes out of scope and is eventually garbage collected, are these two resources then released, or do they remain in memory?

Usually *some* type - often somewhat hidden from the public API - has a handle on a native resource, possibly via [`SafeHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and that's what ends up releasing the resource. It's *possible* to write code which doesn't do this, of course, in which case the native resources would only be released on process exit through the normal OS clean-up, but I'd expect any Microsoft-provided APIs to do the right thing.

Of course, you should still dispose of resources explicitly :)

Answer (score 1):

Any object that directly uses an unmanaged resource like a file handle or a database connection should always implement a [finalizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that releases the unmanaged resource. When the object is garbage collected the finalizer is executed and the unmanaged resource is freed. So to answer your question:

> When this object goes out of scope and is eventually garbage collected, are these two resources then released, or do they remain in memory?

**Yes**, the unmanaged resources will eventually be freed by the garbage collector that calls the **finalizer** of the object.

As you are aware of, leaving it to the garbage collector to clean up unmanaged resources is normally a bad thing. If you open and read a file you would prefer that the file is closed and available to other processes when the read has completed instead at some random future time when the garbage collector decides to release the now unused file object.

.NET provides the [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface to enable deterministic release of unmanaged resources. When you dispose a `FileStream` object the underlying unmanaged file handle is released and the file is closed.

An important part of implementing the `IDisposable` interface is that if the unmanaged resource is released via a call to `Dispose` then the object no longer needs to be finalized. That is why you see a call to [`GC.SuppressFinalize(this)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.suppressfinalize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) when an object implements `IDisposable` and has a finalizer. Avoiding finalization is a good thing to reduce the amount of resources that the garbage collector has to use. Also, finalizers run within tight constraints established by the garbage collector so they are best avoided.

Note that most of the time your objects will not have a finalizer because you do not use any unmanaged resource. Instead you will get access to unmanaged resources using a managed objects like `SafeHandle`. In that case the object does not need a finalizer but should implement `IDisposable` and forward calls to `Dispose` to any aggregated `IDisposable` objects.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: They are automatic released.

Just one time, years ago, I got a inexplicable memory leak due to a object not being released. 
At the time I need to put some explicit call to the garbage collector to fix the problem.

Never found the real cause, maybe a framework bug, maybe something to do with a OS resource but I can say 99.99% of time you can be free of worries about it in C#.

Comment: Memory leaks are usually not strongly related to Dispose and resources.

Comment: In general you are right, but for that particular issue explicit calling GB fixed the problem. It was ages ago with 1.1.4322 framework